# Opening file in True Basic Bronze Demo

Tags: file-io, basic

I am new to True Basic and I am trying to open a file to read with True Basic Bronze demo version. The demo version does not allow you to save files, so I am unsure how to do this. I have moved the demo launcher and the files I want to be opened into the same directory, but I keep getting the an error when I try opening the file. I have also tried specifying which directory by doing "LIBRARY C:\...\TrueBASIC BRONZE v6 Demo" but am still getting the error. Just want to know if anyone knows how to fix this, or if the demo version even has this capability or not. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Their version of BASIC is pretty succinct ([borrowed from here](https://www.truebasic.com/node/1033))

```
INPUT PROMPT “Name of file to display: “: fname$ OPEN #1: NAME fname$
DO WHILE MORE #1
LINE INPUT #1: line$ PRINT line$
LOOP END
```